# Face Detection and scaling with ImageView not quite working due to scaling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, core-image, quartz-core

Once again, I'm close, but no banana.

I'm trying to follow some tutorials on facial recognition. Almost there with the following code, but I think there is something I'm missing with how it's scaling and placing the `UIImageView` borders around the faces.

My photos in the Photo Library are different sizes (for some inexplicable reason), and so I'm imagining that the `CIDetector` is finding the faces, I'm applying the `CGAffineTransforms` etc, and trying to place them in the `UIImageView`. But, as you can see from the image (also below), it's not getting drawn in the correct place.

The `UIImageView` is 280x500 and set as Scale to Fill.

Any help to work out what's happening would be great!

```
-(void)detectFaces {

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:_imagePhotoChosen.image.CGImage options:nil];
    CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:context options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, -_imagePhotoChosen.image.size.height);
    NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:image];
    NSLog(@"I have found %lu faces", (long unsigned)features.count);
    for (CIFaceFeature *faceFeature in features)
    {   
        const CGRect faceRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.bounds, transform);
        NSLog(@"I have the original frame as: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(faceRect));
        const CGFloat scaleWidth = _imagePhotoChosen.frame.size.width/_imagePhotoChosen.image.size.width;
        const CGFloat scaleHeight = _imagePhotoChosen.frame.size.height/_imagePhotoChosen.image.size.height;

        CGRect faceFrame = CGRectMake(faceRect.origin.x * scaleWidth, faceRect.origin.y * scaleHeight, faceRect.size.width * scaleWidth, faceRect.size.height * scaleHeight);

        UIView *faceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceFrame];
        NSLog(@"I have the bounds as: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(faceFrame));
        faceView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        faceView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

        [self.view addSubview:faceView];
    }

}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    _imagePhotoChosen.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //[_imagePhotoChosen sizeToFit];

    [self.view addSubview:_viewChosenPhoto];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self detectFaces];

}
```

I've left in the NSLog statements as I've been trying to work out if the Mathematics is wrong, but can't seem to see if it is! And I'm a Maths teacher too ... sigh ....

[image: Not quite right now is it?]

Thanks again for anything you can do to point me in the right direction.

### Update

In response to people wanting to know how I solved it ... it really was a silly mistake on my part.

I was adding the subviews to the main window, rather than the `UIImageView`. Hence I removed the line:

```
[self.view addSubview:faceView];
```

And replaced it with:

```
[_imagePhotoChosen addSubview:faceView];
```

This allowed the frames to be placed in the correct place. The accepted solution provided me the clue! So, the updated code (and I've moved on a little since then becomes:

```
-(void)detectFaces:(UIImage *)selectedImage {

    _imagePhotoChosen.image = selectedImage;

    CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:selectedImage.CGImage options:nil];

    CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, -selectedImage.size.height);
    NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:image];
    int i = 0;
    for (CIFaceFeature *faceFeature in features)
    {

        const CGRect faceRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.bounds, transform);

        const CGFloat scaleWidth = _imagePhotoChosen.frame.size.width/_imagePhotoChosen.image.size.width;
        const CGFloat scaleHeight = _imagePhotoChosen.frame.size.height/_imagePhotoChosen.image.size.height;

        CGRect faceFrame = CGRectMake(faceRect.origin.x * scaleWidth, faceRect.origin.y * scaleHeight, faceRect.size.width * scaleWidth, faceRect.size.height * scaleHeight);

        UIView *faceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceFrame];
        faceView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        faceView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        faceView.tag = i;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *selectPhotoTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectPhoto)];
        selectPhotoTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        selectPhotoTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        [faceView addGestureRecognizer:selectPhotoTap];

        [_imagePhotoChosen addSubview:faceView];
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: What I want to know especially is how the faceFrame in answer below solve it.

Comment: faceFrame in the answer below simply took account of the fact that I had placed the subviews in the wrong place. It was calculating the faceView frames properly, but I wasn't placing them inside the `UIImageView`. So adding the `_imagePhotoChosen.frame.origin.x` etc just took account of the placement of the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you did is exactly correct, just replace this line with

```
    CGRect faceFrame = CGRectMake(_imagePhotoChosen.frame.origin.x+ faceRect.origin.x * scaleWidth,_imagePhotoChosen.frame.origin.y+ faceRect.origin.y * scaleHeight, faceRect.size.width * scaleWidth, faceRect.size.height * scaleHeight);
```

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver! I've even sat here with the Maths and trying to make sure all the transforms work! And it was a simple mistake once again. Thanks SO much!!

Comment: And even more stupid when I realise I was adding the subviews to the wrong view. Sigh.

Comment: @Darren Could one of you explain what happened and how the above corrected it?

Comment: "@santhu" & "@Darren" Can you please help me for  detect eyes ?